# Python Автоморфные числа

Tags: python, python-3.x, теория-чисел

Надо решить эту задачу на Python: Натуральное число назывываеься автоморфным, если оно равно последним цифрам своего квадрата. Например 25^2=625, Напишите программу, которая вводит натуральное число N и выводит на экран все автоморфные числа, не превосходящие N.
На данный момент мы имеет это:

```py
N=int(input('N='))
Cel=N

N=N**2  
for i in range(1, N):
    a=i**2
    print('afor',a)                                   
    if a%100==i:
        print(i)
```

программа не работает так, как нужно. Например при вводе 25 он выводит 76, что неверно

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! изложите, пожалуйста, что «не так» с вашим решением, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Здравствуйте! Да, программа не работает так, как нужно. Например при вводе 25 он выводит 76, что неверно

Answer (score 1):

У вас неправильное условие проверки. Наверное лучше посмотреть, что конец символьного представления квадрата кончается самим числом

```
N = int(input('N='))
for i in range(1, N) :
    a = str(i**2)     
    if a[-len(str(i))] == str(i) :
        print('afor',i, a)
```

Comment: Можно, наверное, .endswith() использовать.

Answer (score 0):

Из-за `N=N**2` числа проверяются не до N, а до N в квадрате (т.е. не до 25, а до 625). И сама проверка неправильная.

Answer (score 0):

Без использования строк

```
mod = 10
for i in range(1, N + 1):
    if i == mod:
        mod *= 10
    if (i * i) % mod == i:
        print(i)
```

Comment: как по-вашему, почему [эти ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aa) получили так много голосов «за»? что их принципиально отличает от вашего ответа?